# Zero-W Mail Server Setup

Tags: pi-zero-w, mail-server

I would like to host a 'light-weight' mailserver on a raspberry pi and would like to host it on a rPi Zero-W.  Specific objectives / requirements are:

1. Send / Receive messages less a total of less than 10 messages (light-weight) per day.
2. Send receive from using a .com domain
3. Send / receive from Thunderbird mail client
4. Nice to have: Secure Web UI
5. Bonus round: webserver can serve-up static website, that allows customers to send email from web to contact.myFQDN.com

[Mailserver setup instructions](https://habilisbest.com/raspberry-pi-as-personal-email-server) do not always address hardware requirements.

Is there any limitations that prevent the Zero-W from performing said tasks?  Any lessons-learned from those who have setup a mailserver on the Zero-W is appreciated.

Comment: `Is there any limitations that prevent the Zero-W from performing said tasks?` no, there isn't

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used a RPi Zero-W with a light-weight mailserver but because the RasPi is nearly a general purpose computer there shouldn't be any limitations to use it except the performance. A RPi Zero-W is not the fastest but with your small requirements it should not be a problem.